# How can I make a button's corner only rounded on the top?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a button which has rounded corners on the top and a normal corner on the bottom. How can I make it like this?

Comment: read `BorderRadius` documentation

Comment: Add some code of what you tried  & Screenshot of what you desired..

Comment: instead of `BorderRadius.all` you could use `BorderRadius.only({Radius topLeft: Radius.zero, Radius topRight: Radius.zero, Radius bottomLeft: Radius.zero, Radius bottomRight: Radius.zero })`

Comment: @Potato OP wants corners at top only so `BorderRadius.vertical` would be even easier

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An General Example :

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(15.0))),
              child: Text('Click Me!'),
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
```

As Per pskink Comment :

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: Radius.circular(15.0),
              )),
              child: Text('Click Me!'),
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
```