# Flutter - Quarter round Button

Tags: flutter, button, rounded-corners, cornerradius

For my Flutter App I want that four buttons together are a circle. Here an Image of what i kinda want.
[image]

I don't know how to style the corners of a button in flutter.
In case of button 1 my idea would be to take the upper left corner and set the border radius and leave  the other corners normal. With the other buttons I would do the same with the appropriated corners. To arrange my "pizza slices" i would use Colums and Rows.
I just don't know and couldn't figure out how to style only one corner.

Thanks for everyone in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone here!
I got an solution based of this Question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138955/how-can-i-make-a-buttons-corner-only-rounded-on-the-top]

And based of the answer of @fusion

My solution looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum QuarterPosition { topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight }

class QuarterButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuarterButton({Key? key, required this.position, this.size = 100, this.text = ""}) : super(key: key);

  final QuarterPosition position;
  final double size;
  final String text;

  BorderRadiusGeometry _generateBorderRadius() {
    switch (position) {
      case QuarterPosition.topLeft:
        return BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(size),
        );
      case QuarterPosition.topRight:
        return BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(size),
        );
      case QuarterPosition.bottomLeft:
        return BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(size),
        );
      case QuarterPosition.bottomRight:
        return BorderRadius.only(
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(size),
        );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white)),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.black54,
          fixedSize: Size(size, size),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: _generateBorderRadius(),
              ),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
        );
  }
}
```

And I can use it now like that.

```
Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            QuarterButton(position: QuarterPosition.topLeft, size: 100, text: "1"),
            QuarterButton(position: QuarterPosition.topRight, size: 100, text: "2"),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            QuarterButton(position: QuarterPosition.bottomLeft, size: 100, text: "3"),
            QuarterButton(position: QuarterPosition.bottomRight, size: 100, text: "4"),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Thanks for all the quick answers. Great community! :)

Comment: happy to helping you!
an upvote or an accepted answer would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi I do that with Grid View and "Clip R Rec t"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL8Li.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
            child: Container(
              height: 120,
              width: 120,
              child: GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("1", textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("2", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("3", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("4", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and you can use **Align** Widget and put your numbers in align to you have a beautiful UI like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVEdZ.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
            child: Container(
              height: 120,
              width: 120,
              child: GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment(0.5, 0),
                      child: Text("1", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment(-0.5, 0),
                      child: Text("2", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment(0.5, 0),
                      child: Text("3", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment(-0.5, 0),
                      child: Text("4", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you can compare between images and code and If you liked my answer and it was useful, I will be happy for you to rate my answer.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to create a Container with a fixed width and height. Then you set a background color and the border radius with BorderRadius.only for topLeft, topRight etc.
Now you only have to create a column with two rows containing your respective containers.

E.g.:

```dart
// pizza_button.dart
enum PizzaPosition { topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight }

class PizzaButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final PizzaPosition pizzaPosition;
  final _buttonSize = 60.0;

  const PizzaButton({Key? key, required this.pizzaPosition}) : super(key: key);

  BorderRadiusGeometry? _generateBorderRadius() {
    switch (pizzaPosition) {
      case PizzaPosition.topLeft:
        return BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(_buttonSize),
        );
      case PizzaPosition.topRight:
        return BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(_buttonSize),
        );
      case PizzaPosition.bottomLeft:
        return BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_buttonSize),
        );
      case PizzaPosition.bottomRight:
        return BorderRadius.only(
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(_buttonSize),
        );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: _buttonSize,
      height: _buttonSize,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: _generateBorderRadius(),
      ),
      child: Text("1"),
    );
  }
}
```

And for the whole "pizza" an example widget would be

```dart
class Pizza extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              PizzaButton(pizzaPosition: PizzaPosition.topLeft),
              PizzaButton(pizzaPosition: PizzaPosition.topRight),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              PizzaButton(pizzaPosition: PizzaPosition.bottomLeft),
              PizzaButton(pizzaPosition: PizzaPosition.bottomRight),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now to have it work as buttons you should wrap the containers inside PizzaButton in GestureDetectors and specify your action `onTap` which can be hold as another property of PizzaButton for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it inside a card like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My App'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 120,
              height: 120,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Text("1"),
                                )),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Text("2"),
                                )),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Text("1"),
                                )),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Text("2"),
                                )),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```